# C infinite loop breaks with code 141 when opening two threads after accepting connection

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

In a simple C program I'm opening a new thread everytime an incoming connection on a TCP socket was accepted to handle the client input asynchronously. The accept is happening in an infinite loop. Client data is processed in the callback function passed to pthread_create. The socket will immediately be shutdown when the client sent it's data and will be disconnected.

As soon as i connect - with a telnet client - to the port the program listens on, the program is ready to accept new connections. So far so good.

Now, when I'm connecting two clients at the same time and give it some input one after another the main program will exit with **code 141**.

**Server Console**

```
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $ ./sysmon 
Thu Apr  9 12:03:17 2015: Finished reading configuration file
Thu Apr  9 12:03:17 2015: Initializing server socket
Thu Apr  9 12:03:17 2015: Accepting connections...
Thu Apr  9 12:03:19 2015: Inbound connection from  127.0.0.1
Using Thread: 0
Thu Apr  9 12:03:19 2015: Accepting connections...
Thu Apr  9 12:03:22 2015: Inbound connection from  127.0.0.1
Using Thread: 1
Thu Apr  9 12:03:22 2015: Accepting connections...
Client msg: asdf
Client msg: asdfasdfdsfadsf
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $ echo $?
141
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $
```

**Client Console 1**

```
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $ telnet 127.0.0.1 50231
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
asdfasdfdsfadsf
Connection closed by foreign host.
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $
```

**Client Console 2**

```
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $ telnet 127.0.0.1 50231
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
asdf
Message was: asdf
Connection closed by foreign host.
cehrig@devbox /home/cehrig/projects/SystemMonitor/build $
```

This is a snipped from the function used to accept the connections.

```
int connections = 0;
pthread_t * newthread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

while(1) {
    _print(stdout, "messages.socketacceppt", cfg, 1);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    thrpass_st thr_pass;
    thr_pass.sockfd = newsockfd;
    thr_pass.cfg = cfg;

    _print(stdout, "messages.socketreceived", cfg, 0);
    fprintf(stdout, "%d.%d.%d.%d\n",
        cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF,
        (cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF00)>>8,
        (cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF0000)>>16,
        (cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF000000)>>24);

    printf("Using Thread: %d\n", connections);
    pthread_create(newthread+connections, NULL, &read_socket, (void *) &thr_pass);

    newthread = (pthread_t *) realloc(newthread, (++connections+1)*sizeof(pthread_t));
}
```

This is the callback function / entry point for every new thread.

```
void * read_socket(void * args)
{
    thrpass_st * _args = (thrpass_st *) malloc(sizeof(thrpass_st));
    _args = (thrpass_st *) args;

    int n;
    char * _buf = (char *) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
    char * _cor = (char *) malloc(512*sizeof(char));
    char * _out = _cor;

    bzero(_buf, 512);
    bzero(_cor, 512);


    size_t bread = 0;
    do {
        if((n = read(_args->sockfd, _buf+bread, 512-bread)) < 0) {
            _print(stderr, "messages.socketreadfail", _args->cfg, 1);
            _exit(0);
        }
        bread+=n;
    } while(strchr(_buf, '\n') == NULL && bread <= 512);


    int x = 0;
    while(*_buf != '\n' && x++ <= 512) {
        *_cor++ = *_buf++;
    }

    printf("Client msg: %s\n", _out);
    fflush(stdout);

    FILE * sstream = fdopen(_args->sockfd, "w+");
    fprintf(sstream, "Message was: %s\n", _out);
    fflush(sstream);
    shutdown(_args->sockfd, 2);
}
```

I think the problem is somewhere at the end of this function as the second telnet client does not receive the "Message sent:" line.

Any help would be apprecitated! Cheers.

Comment: When you have an exit code more than 128, it's probably a signal. You can find the signal codes [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7), a return value is the signal code + 128. So in your case, it is the SIGPIPE: write to pipe with no readers. You probably wrote on a closed or ended file descriptor. I recommend to not use fdopen on network file descriptors as sockets. It's more used in file management.

Comment: thx for the hint with streams vs. writing directly to the fd. it was more or less playing around with streams instead of using the 'normal' low level way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and you have this UB in your thread functions, stemming from these lines:

```
thrpass_st * _args = (thrpass_st *) malloc(sizeof(thrpass_st));
_args = (thrpass_st *) args;
```

The first line allocates memory, but then you overwrite the pointer to this memory, with another pointer, a pointer which points to a local variable inside another function, a variable which goes out of scope as soon as the `accept` loop iterates.

The simplest solution is to copy the structure:

```
*_args = *(thrpass_st *) args;
```

---

Actually, there's no need for the pointer at all in this case, just do eg.

```
thrpass_st _args = *(thrpass_st *) args;
```

That way will also not have the memory leak from forgetting to `free` the pointer at the end of the thread.

---

Also note that you have a *race condition* here. If two clients connects very closely together, then there is a risk that both threads will have the same structure data passed as an argument.

A *proper* solution would then be to allocate the memory for the argument structure in the loop, ad pass that pointer to the thread function. And don't forget to `free` the memory at the end of the thread function of course.

Comment: 'race condition' It's worse than that - the threads may get a sliced struct copied in:(

Comment: argh, sorry for annoying :-/ ... as you said, in the thread function i just initialized a new structure variable with the contents of the struct pointer passed to the thread function

Comment: If you are not dynamically-allocating the struct in the accept() loop, or otherwise ensuring that each client<>server thread has unique access to its own struct instance, your server will be unreliable.

Comment: Allright. When I'm doing dynamic allocation of the argument structure i don't have to create a new variable inside the thread function, right? Just cast the pointer to my type and use it directly.

Comment: @ChristianEhrig yes, exactly that, cast the pointer to your type* (and free it on thread exit, as suggested by others).